# How do I create a java-script library- for tracking user action on a website from scratch?

Tags: javascript, web, google-analytics, sdk

There i am required to write a javaScript SDK  which will track users click event on any website(Similar to GA),and submit few parameter to db,i would like to know how to start and any reference would be helpful. 
PS: Have read about piwik :) would like to know how to write from scratch .

Comment: where do you save this data? you will need more then Javascript you need server side code as well to make this work with a database? have you considered all these factors before you start?

Comment: have REST service to call the DB

Comment: so what do you want me to give you a example on.. i cant show you how to write it all but i can show you a example?

Comment: That would would helpful,tracking a click event let say when ever the user clicks on a anchor tag  get id and store in array .I'm not sure sure how to structure the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok first of you will need server side code and a database to store this data but as you stated you want a simple example of how you would structure a click event.

First off you would always need the user to pass something to your function like google analytics even though its all there for you the developer website still needs to do some integration to pass the data into the API for example the dataLayer.

so lets say for example someone is using your API and trying to pass in data from a click event.. you would create a global function for them to push the data in to.

User website

```
// reference your API
<script src="www.whereyourapiscriptishosted.com/myscripts.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <a href="clickevent.com" id="clickeventtracker">Track me</a>
</div> 

<script type="text/javascript">
// this is where they call your api
$("#clickeventtracker").click(function() {
    api.trackcode($(this).attr('id'));
});
</script>
```

You want to make your API function as reusable as possible but integration is always needed for the user on there side. You can expand this function and pass in more parameters make it more complicated but this is just a simple example i have gave.

api code simple example:

```
api.trackcode function(Id){
  if (Id != undefined){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/services/YourRestfullService/Yourmethod',
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        async: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ Id: Id }),
        success: function (data) {
            // success do nothing
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            api.trackcode(error);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Then in your server side code you can track this data count how many people click in or don't click it etc. Obviously this is a very simple example but i hope it helps you.

Thanks
Josh

Comment: Thank You Josh, Helpful.